# How to send variables from client sided code to server sided code

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-api

I am using the `Google API` to sign in users . They can sign in but i need to then send the information to the server side code from the client side

I'm not to sure how to approach this, i have looked at [sending data from client side to server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083079/sending-data-from-client-side-to-server-side) but i couldn't find a solution

here is my HTML

```html
<!-- sign in button -->
<div id="signin" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<!-- The client sided function -->
<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // get user profile information
    console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile())
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    document.getElementById("signin").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "block"
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way that I can send `googleUser.getBasicProfile()` to my server side code, or just have the `onSignIn()` function server side and it runs that

Comment: Use AJAX for this purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: Have you explored [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)?